# Django - Website Home Page

Tags: python, django

I've been having a look at Django and, from what I've seen, it's pretty darn fantastic. I'm a little confused, however, how I go about implementing a "home page" for my website? Would it be a separate app, or just a view within the project, or what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no real rule for this, But one thing I like to do is actually arrange for the index access to redirect to another spot.  If you prefer, though, you can just give the index page a plain view.

That said, It's probably a good idea to keep all your code in an actual app, so that you can refactor it more easily, and so that it appears on the python path as a normal module.  Putting views in the project rather than an app seems to cause more headaches than it solves.

Answer (score 3):

I just found my original approach (`direct_to_template`) is deprecated in Django 1.5

Instead, use a `TemplateView` to achieve the same result

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'),
        name='index'),
)
```

(**For Django 1.4**) You can setup a `direct_to_template` url within `./project/project/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', direct_to_template, { 'template': 'index.html'}),
    # add urls to apps here
)
```

For both, place the template (`index.html`) in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` root. This is one approach to create a homepage without implementing an entire app. There are many ways to make this happen as others have noted.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  One quibble -- the Django setting is `TEMPLATE_DIRS` with an S; can be a list.  Not `TEMPLATE_DIR`.

Comment: patterns is not supported anymore in the newer versions

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using Django's "Flatpages".  See this link for more info:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/

Comment: Flatpages works as advertised, but I've found that I almost never have a use for static content.  For instance a home page will often need to display 'top ten posts' or different inserts based on user preferences.