# Universally usable files for django project - Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am making a django project and within the project I have 3 different apps. registration, users, groups. I dont want to have to print all of the import statements in the views.py file for each app. I also dont want to have to retype any of the methods for functions in each of the views.py file for small functions like generatingRandomNumbers. Is there a way to create a single file within the project directory that has all of the import statements or all of the methods that i can call at the beginning of each views.py file....

Also where would i put the file if possible, and how can i call the fill with all of the import statements at the top of each of the views.py file so i dont have to keep retyping all of it...

Here is my current directory:

[image]

[image]

Another question is how can i setup the urls in a way that i can redirect to any url within the project no matter which app it is localated in... Django documentation does not explain any of this at all...
 an example would be a view in the registration app redirects to a url in the users app.. Here is what i have:

registration -> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.Signup, name='user_signup'),
    url(r'^setup_profile/$', views.ProfileSetup, name='profile_setup'),
]
```

users -> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', views.UserHome, name='home_page'),
]
```

redirect statement from the registrations -> views.py file:

```
return redirect('user_home')
```

Comment: The usual practice is to have a separate app (such as `common`) to keep such shared resources. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661583/django-project-wide-common-resources) for a discussion.

Comment: thanks for that. I have a question beyond that. I am creating a file in a common app that has all of the commonly used methods between different apps within the project. what would the import statement for the files with methods look like.... if file name is methods.py in the common app, would you use `from ..common import methods `  or `from ..common.methods import *` @Selcuk

Comment: Recently I was facing the same issue in my project. I have found the solution up with the common package in one of the app and access throughout the appname.package name.